# JSF saves objects to database without telling to do so

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I am using JSF 2.2 and Hibernate 4.3.1.

I have this class

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class StudentController{

    private StudentUtil studentUtil = new StudentUtil();

    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentUtil.getAllStudents();
    }

    public void verify(Student student){
        student.setVerified(true);
    }
}
```

StudentUtil is my Hibarnate utility class. It fetches all rows in student table in database. In XHTML page I list all students in a data table.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{studentController.students}" 
             var="student">
    ...
    <h:column>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Verify" 
                             action="#{studentController.verify(student)}/>
        </form>
     </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

This code works fine. When I click verify button it sets the `verified` field of `Student` class to `true`, but unexpected to me, it also sets the field in the database to true even tough I don't perform any database operations. `setVerified` is basically a setter which Hibernate generates.

Can you please explain how it works and if it is safe to use this way.

Thanks.

Comment: It's rather JPA question. Read more about managed and detached entities/objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with attached entities. In this case any entity change will trigger a database update.

If you are using EJB as a service of StudentUtil all loaded entities are detachted automatically. Otherwise you have to detach them by yourself.

Comment: I am sorry for posting with wrong tags. I guess my objects stayed managed since I didn't close the session after query. I used `openSession()`